# How to generate jar file on Windows terminal compiler?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

I have an old project with all files and folders and its jar file (`xyz_2.11-1.0.jar`) was at `target\scala-2.11\` folder, and I removed it to replace by a new fresh one... I do and redo with similar final results:

1. `cd xyz`
2. `sbt`: say "[info] Loading settings from assembly.sbt ..." and seems all ok.
3. `compile`: say "[success] Total time: 11 s, completed"
4. `package`: say "[success] Total time: 6 s, completed"

But `target\scala-2.11\` folder is empty, no new jar file!

**How to compile and generate the jar file?**

Comment: Can you add the output of `sbt package`? Usually it writes where the jar is (unless you decreased the verbosity level)

Comment: Hi @TomerShetah, how to increase the *"verbosity level"*?  The message is only that with time, ""[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 17/02/2021 20:50:10"

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to check the behavior using the latest stable version sbt 1.4.7 as opposed to sbt 1.1.5 from 2018. Because it seems like you missed the fix by one patch version.

This issue was reported in 2018 as https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4118, and was later fixed by dadarakt also in 2018 as https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/4161, which released in sbt 1.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the source code (anything at `/src/main`) **the procedure saved the jar file**.

So, the SBT v1.1.5 logic is: not save jar when no changes... It is not a bug, but perhaps need a [new issue for next SBT versions](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues):
If there are no jar file (deleted) it need to save one.

---

To change the "verbose level" I used `logLevel := Level.Info` and `logLevel := Level.Debug`.

About jar file complete path, only the `Debug` "verbose level" shows it,

```
[debug] No changes
[debug] Jar uptodate: C:\Users\myUser\etc\xyz\target\scala-2.11\xyz_2.11-1.0.jar
```

But `dir C:\Users\myUser\etc\xyz\target\scala-2.11\xyz_2.11-1.0.jar` say "file not found". Only **after source code changes** it saved.